# How do I pass a variable to a function that then changes the variable depending on an if statement?

Tags: rust, filesystems, lifetime-scoping

I do not understand how to properly set up this line of logic without my variables going out of scope. I am trying to create the below function chunk_file. My first if statement ensures that the passed file does exist and that it is to be chunked by more than 0 bytes. The second if statement is checking that the file was passed from the directory I want all files to originate from and if it doesn't then I want it to change the Path and move the file to the correct directory. The issue is that no matter where I place the temp variable it's lifetime is dropped and cannot be borrowed but I see no other way to redefine src_path with the new path.

```
let test = Path::new(r"C:\\temp\\files\\test.txt");

fn main () {
    chunk_file(src_path: test, constant::CHUNK_SIZE_8MB);

}

fn chunk_file(mut src_path: &Path, chunk_size: u32) -> bool {
    let result = false;
    let file_directory: &Path = constant::FILE_DIRECTORY.as_ref();

    if src_path.exists() && chunk_size > 0 {
        if src_path.parent().unwrap() != file_directory {
            let mut temp: String = String::from("");
            temp.push_str(string: file_directory.to_str().unwrap());
            temp.push_str(string: src_path.file_name().unwrap().to_str().unwrap());
            match fs::rename(from: src_path, to: &temp) {
                Ok(_) => {}
                Err(e: Error) => println!("Error in file rename => {:?}", e) 
            }
            src_path = Path::new(&temp) 
        }
        else {
            src_path = src_path
        }
    }

result
}
```

I have placed temp inside the innermost if statement, inside the outermost if statement, in the main function, outside of the main function and I either get a temp gets dropped error or that I need to make the function a variable [ let chunk_file = || { \code } ] which is not at all what I need as it needs to be a function.
I have tried dereferencing and get the error you cannot dereference a &mut variable.
I have tried making a [ let src_check = if \logic { \code } variable and then doing src_path = Path::new(&src_check) ] and this still returns a &src_check is dropped while still borrowed.

Comment: What will setting `src_path` give you if you never read the value back? (Also, did you copy inlay hints? How?)

Comment: First step should be resolving all of the syntax errors in the code you provided.

Comment: Could you elaborate?
I am new to learning Rust and the concept of ownership backed by variable lifetimes has been difficult for me to grasp. I know that my outer if statement does not have an else statement yet but I can not even get past the logic of the inner if statement

Comment: @ChayimFriedman following this inner if statement I plan to create a chunk header from the src_path: &Path
Problem is that as it is now I cannot edit that original path and return the new Path
And I simply retyped everything instead of just copying it over. That way I could show how each variables type was being considered by the compiler

Comment: let header = ChunkHeader {
    identifier: 0,
    src_file_dir: src_path.parent().unwrap(),
    src_file_path: src_path,
    chunk_dir: constant::FILE_CHUNK_DIRECTORY.as_ref(),
    src_file_name: src_path.file_name().unwrap().to_str().unwrap(),
    src_file_size: src_path.metadata().unwrap().len(),
    src_file_start_index: 0,
    chunk_size: constant::CHUNK_SIZE_8MB,
    chunk_count: 0,
    creation_time: UNIX_EPOCH,
    last_modification: UNIX_EPOCH,
    last_access: UNIX_EPOCH,
};
println!("Successfully created a header\n{:?}", header);

Comment: If you want to return the new path from the function, then the TL;DR is "you can't do that". If you only want to use it inside the function, define at the beginning `let mut src_path = src_path;` and it should work (haven't tested though).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Thank you that has made it work so far and should continue to do so! From here I should be able to complete the chunking function and then create a reassembly function independent of this one.